# 'Exception in thread Main....' error in Java

Tags: java, exception

I am really a novice at Java but I'm giving it a shot with this program. This is a program to perform basic mathematical calculations, but with input from user.

```
import java.io.*;  
import java.util.Scanner;  

public class Math 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);  

        int sa1, sa2, ss1, ss2, sm1, sm2, s;  
    boolean c = false;  
    double sd1, sd2;  

        while(c==false)  
        {
        System.out.print("Do you want to: \n[1] Add. \n[2] Subtract.  \n[3] Multiply.  \n[4] Divide. \n[5] Exit \nPlease insert an option number below and press enter:  ");  
        s = in.nextInt();  

        if (s==1)  
            {
            System.out.print("You have chosen option 1 \nPlease enter your first number: ");  
            sa1 = in.nextInt();  
            System.out.print("Please enter your second number: ");  
            sa2 = in.nextInt();  
            System.out.print(sa1+ " + " +sa2+ " = " +(sa1+sa2));  
            }
        if (s==2)  
            {
            System.out.print("You have chosen option 2 \nPlease enter your first number: ");  
            ss1 = in.nextInt();  
            System.out.print("Please enter your second number: ");  
            ss2 = in.nextInt();  
            System.out.println(ss1+ " - " +ss2+ " = " +(ss1-ss2));  
            }
        if (s==3)
            {
            System.out.print("You have chosen option 3 \nPlease enter your first number: ");  
            sm1 = in.nextInt();  
            System.out.print("Please enter your second number: ");  
            sm2 = in.nextInt();  
            System.out.println(sm1+ " x " +sm2+ " = " +(sm1*sm2));  
            }
        if (s==4)       
            {       
            System.out.print("You have chosen option 4 \nPlease enter your first number: ");  
            sd1 = in.nextDouble();  
            System.out.print("Please enter your second number: ");  
            sd2 = in.nextDouble();  
            System.out.println(sd1+ " divided by " +sd2+ " = " +(sd1/sd2));    
            }       
            if(s>=6)  
            {
            System.out.println("You have entered an incorrect option");    
            }
        System.out.print("Would you like to try again? (Y/N): ");   
        String ans = in.nextLine();//prob with this line   
        char ans1 = ans.charAt(0);//or this line  
            if (ans1=='N' || ans1=='n')  
            {
            c = true;   
            }
            if(s==5)   
            {
            c = true;  
            }       
        } 

    }

}
```

When I complile it I get an error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
 at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
 at Math.main(Math.java:58)

I've tried searching everywhere for an answer. Can anyone help me with this? It needs to be able to read either a 'Y' or a 'N' from the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the exception when you run it. Not when you compile it. And the error message says:

> you're trying to get the char at index 0 of a string, but the String has no index 0. This exception happens at line 58 of Main.java.

A String which doesn't have a char at index 0 is an empty string.

This probably happens because the last thing you read from SYstem.in() is a number, and reading a number doesn't consume the end-of-line that comes after. Add a call to readLine() before reading Yes or No from the user. And don't assume that the user will do what you tell him to do. That's almost never true. Validate the inputs you read.

Comment: alternately, use `String ans = in.next();` instead of `nextLine()`

Comment: Thanks for the advice Nizet. And your comments.

Bane I tried your method and it worked out beautifully. Thanks tya too!!

Comment: Took your advice Nizet and modified the program to be fool proof. Enter any value and it prompts you in case you entered an incorrect value.